# Accessing "~" (user home) from Java in Linux

Tags: java, file

I need to create a configuration file in ~/.config/myapp.cfg So I am doing this with `File`:

```
File f;
f = new File("~/.config/gfgd.gfgdf");
if(!f.exists()){
    f.createNewFile();
}
```

The problem is, that it tell me, that directory doesn't exist and something like this.

```
java.io.IOException: Not such file or directory
    at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
```

I tried changing path to something like /home/user and it worked. So i managed to make a conclusion, that java doesn't know what ~/ means and what a punct(.) before foldername means too, because /home/user/.config doesn not work aswell.

What should I do?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

The `~` notation is a shell thing. Read up on [shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html).

Java doesn't understand this notation. To get hold of the home directory, get the [system property](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) with key `user.home`:

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File f = new File(home + "/.config/gfgd.gfgdf");
```

(As a bonus, it will work on windows machines too ;-)

Answer (score 10):

User the `user.home` System property.  To completely avoid operating system dependencies you should let File do the path resolution, like this:

```
f = new File(new File (System.getProperty("user.home"),".config"),"gfgd.gfgdf");
```

Comment: Java accepts `/` as file separator regardless of operating system, so no worries using `.config/gfgd.gfgdf`.

Comment: @aioobe the fact that Sun promotes the use of File.separator or File.separatorChar led me to believe that while this may be true on Unixen and Windows it is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using directly the `~` shortcut, you should use (it also works on Windows)

```
System.getProperty("user.home");
```

Example :

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.config/gfgd.gfgdf");
if (!f.exists()) {
    f.createNewFile();
}
```