# IOException while sending message - File Not Found

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot, jakarta-mail, filenotfoundexception

I am sending an mail with an inline image but the problem is that it gives me an error of `FileNotFound` I am using the correct path but still error throws anyone can tell me where I am wrong ?

***Code***

```
public void forgotPasswordMail(String email,String token)
    {
          String to = email;
          Properties props = new Properties();
          props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
          props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
          props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
          Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
             new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                   return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
           }
             });
          try {
                Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                  message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
                  message.setSubject("Reset Password");
                  message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                             InternetAddress.parse(to));

                       MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart("related");
                       BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                       String htmlText = //"<img src=\"cid:image\"> " + 
                       "<html><head><style>h1 {background-color: #FFF100;padding: 15px; text-indent: 40px;} " +
                          "p {text-indent: 60px;}</style></head><body><h1>Forgot password request</h1> " +
                           "<p> Please click on the following link to set new password</p>" + 
                           "<p>" + frontendUrl+"resetForgottonPassword/"+token+"</p></div></body></html>";

                       messageBodyPart.setContent(htmlText, "text/html");
                       // add it
                       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                       messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

                       DataSource fds = new FileDataSource(
                          "/home/tahir/sportsacademy-backend/assets/Logo.png");
                       messageBodyPart.setFileName("logo.png");
                       messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
                       messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<image>");}

                       multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart); 
                       message.setContent(multipart);
                       Transport.send(message); 
                 System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");

          } catch (MessagingException e) {
             throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
       }
```

And file also have read write both rights

**File Location**

[image: File is prresent here]

Comment: What message is coming with `FileNotFoundException`? It could be that your application user doesn't have permissions to access it.

Comment: is this working in an web context environment?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons that might cause that but I would guess that the problem is that you are looking for the file in your file system location and your program is running in a web context where the root folder is different. If you are making a web application even if you develop in your /home folder it is running in a web context provided by a servlet container or from your IDE using embeded servlet container). And the actual folder structure is a bit different. That's because in a shared web applications environment there is encapsulation and each application can access only files that are part of it (otherwise you might be able to modify files which are not yours).

So in order to check that and if you are running in a web enviornment you can check the actual folder by invoking getRealPath("/") method on your servlet context which shows you the actual filesystem path. But basically you need to access resources using their relative path in the web app context and not in the file system.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the path of the file is incorrect because you use the home folder. Have you checked this post: [Accessing "~" (user home) from Java in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7463545/accessing-user-home-from-java-in-linux) ?

There is another thing; you end the try block, then add some code and afterwards the catch block is started. That does not work because the catch has to start immediately after the try (but maybe it was copied wrong).